# How to add data to registry before installing service using windows installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, c#-3.0, windows-installer

I written windows service in c# which reads some data from registry.Then I created windows installer using visual Studio 2010 for that service and also adding data to registry required for service. My problem is installer starts installing service before adding data to installer.I wanted to add data to registry before installing service so that it can use that data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an installer such as WiX (Windows Installer for XML) or Installshield you will be able to write your registry settings as part of the install using standard MSI instructions.

Then when your service starts, the registry settings will be there as expected.

Incidentally using the self-install feature (via Installutil) is handy for debugging and development but not recommended for production installs.

Personally I use WiX for all my installer needs as it is both free and very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for has to do with the `InstallerClass`

In the `InstallerClass` you can override a number of events either before, during of after the installation.

Check out this link to get started:

http://devblog.grinn.net/2008/02/windows-services-in-c-part-3-getting.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Is there any way using windows installer in visual studio 2010,so that we can add data to registry before installing the service other than Installer class. Because for installing the service I need data from registry.

Comment: I don't understand. Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer_events It shows you all the events you can use. So in the BeforeInstall event you can go into the Registry if you like, get your values, and use them for your installation.

Comment: @Abhi,  One technique is to create and launch a separate program that reads/writes data to the Registry, before launching the installer. The small program and the main installer can be packaged onto one msi file or a simple batch script.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid, the MSI installer is transactional. When you add a separate program the manipulates the target system your break the transaction concept. You can't handle any failure that occurs later in installation process and requires a rollback. Hence, don't do that.